# Is there an open-source, offline calendar software?

Tags: open-source, calendar, offline

Is there an open-source calendar software that **does not** save data in a server?

I searched for `open-source calendar software`, but the results all use servers to store data. I also need it to work offline.

Comment: If you don't find anything you can always run a [calendar](http://radicale.org/) [server](http://baikal-server.com/) locally, the ones I linked are pretty lightweight.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Also: What are your specific requirements? What features should the calendar software have? Just display calendar dates will probably not be all you want :) Please [edit] your question and add some more details. Thanks!

Comment: Thunderbird has a built-in calender/organizer, if you want that kind of thing.